# What is the Bluetooth Version of CC2541 (HM10)

Tags: bluetooth, hm-10

I am looking at the [Datasheet of HM10's IC (aka CC2541)](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cc2541.pdf?ts=1647513126380&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F), and it says "Bluetooth v4.0 Compliant Protocol Stack" at page 2:

[image: blt version]

But in [TI's website for this IC](https://www.ti.com/product/CC2541), they say "Bluetooth Low Energy 5.0".

[image: CC2541]

I guess their website is just doing marketing for the Bluetooth version. I trust the Datasheet more. But HM10 modules is a popular product (for Arduino-based projects at least). So I hope someone can be more specific of the actual version of the Bluetooth specification.

What is the Bluetooth version of the IC?

Comment: good instinct trusting the datasheet!

Comment: I honestly think this is mostly a question for the TI sales people

Comment: Do you want the version this IC could support in a different product, or the version as supported by this IC in this specific product? Those can be very different things. Also remember that many BLE5 features are optional, a chip or device can be compliant without support for all of them.

Comment: @jcaron The answer from Chris Knudsen is the correct answer, the version of the IC was originally Version4, but when Version5 BLT specifications came out, it was still compatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to be a matter of when the device datasheet was written, and software/protocol updates.

From https://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/swru271 "CC2540/41 Bluetooth Low Energy Software Developer’s Guide (Rev. I)" we see on page 8:
[image]

Comment: Oh man, I never read the revision history. Looks like this time was useful!